# Telegram API edit media post with text post

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to edit message and receiving: Telegram API response: `'Bad Request: there is no text in the message to edit', Error code: 400`

I think, I know the issue - I'm trying to edit a media post(post with an image) with plain text post. Is it possible via Telegram API ? I mean not to edit media post with media post but media post with post without image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have media post with text and you want to edit text, just use 'editMessageCaption'